# AWS AMI region to region move

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ami

I'm trying to copy AWS AMI's from region to region automatically. I've found the basic script to move one at a time:

```
aws ec2 copy-image --source-image-id ami-51e1c434 --source-region us-east-2 --region us-west-2 --name "XXX"
```

But I was hoping to automate this process to grab new AMI's and move them to a different region. Any ideas on how I would do this? I've been trying to script with AWS CLI but i'm coming up short!

Comment: I'm not aware of any way to receive notifications when a new AMI is created. That makes it difficult to automate this process. Are you creating the AMIs via some automated process already? Or are you creating them manually?

Comment: When you say "AWS AMI's", are you referring to AMIs created by AWS (eg the standard set of Quick Launch Linux & Windows AMIs), or AMIs that *you* have created?

Comment: I currently have a lambda function that is automatically taking the AMI's

Comment: You have to request them one at a time, techically, but if you're using Node in Lambda, doing them all asynchronously in parallel with the SDK and async-waterfall should be trivial.  Presumably other Lambda environments, either async or multi-threaded.  Or fire off individual Lambda invocations, one per region, but invoke them all asynchronously so the caller doesn't have to wait for them to complete.